# Find where graph has vertical tangent line and confirm with limit calculations.

Tags: calculus, limits, limits-without-lhopital

I am trying to find where the graph of $f(x)=x^{2/3}-(x-1)^{1/3}$ has a vertical tangent line.  I then need to confirm my findings using limit calculations.  This is a problem from a book that I am doing for fun.

Plotting the graph shows what appears to be a vertical tangent line at $x=1$.  The plot is seen in the following image:
[image]

Now I would like to confirm using limit calculations.  I have
\begin{align*}
\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{f(x_0+h)-f(x_0)}{h}&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{\left[(1+h)^{2/3}-(1 + h - 1)^{1/3}\right]-\left[1^{2/3}-(1-1)^{1/3}\right]}{h}\\
&=\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+h)^{2/3}-h^{1/3}-1}{h}.
\end{align*}
At this point, I'm stuck, as I don't know how to proceed.  The term $(1 + h)^{2/3}$ in particular is giving me problems.  Obviously, from the graph, I am expecting a result of $\pm\infty$ for the limit, but I just don't know what to do.  Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: But this limit does exist. See also your picture.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^{2/3}-1}h\tag1$$is the derivative at $1$ of $x\mapsto(1+x)^{2/3}$ (which is $\frac23$). So, you only need to see that$$\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h^{1/3}}h=\lim_{h\to0}h^{-2/3}=\infty.$$

If you want to avoid differentiation, you can prove that $(1)$ is equal to $\frac23$ as follows:\begin{align}(1)&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{\left((1+h)^{2/3}-1\right)\left((1+h)^{4/3}+(1+h)^{2/3}+1\right)}{h\left((1+h)^{4/3}+(1+h)^{2/3}+1\right)}\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{(1+h)^2-1}{h\left((1+h)^{4/3}+(1+h)^{2/3}+1\right)}\\&=\lim_{h\to0}\frac{h+2}{(1+h)^{4/3}+(1+h)^{2/3}+1}\\&=\frac23.\end{align}

Comment: How are you finding the value of that limit $\lim_{h\rightarrow 0}\frac{(1+h)^{2/3}-1}{h}$ to be $2/3$?

Comment: If $g(x)=x^{2/3}$, $g'(x)=\frac23x^{-1/3}$.

Comment: Yes I know, but the instructions for this problem are to use limit calculations.  I don't have the power rule and such at this point in the book.

Comment: I've edited my answer. What do you think now?

Comment: I like it a lot.  I just wish I knew how you thought to do that.

Comment: After having some practice, this becomes natural.

Answer (score 0):

At $x=0, 1$, the tangent is vertical to the curve. As $$y'(x)=\frac{2}{3}x^{-1/3}-\frac{1}{3}(x-1)^{-2/3} \implies y'(0)= \infty, y'(1)=\infty$$

Comment: Sorry but the instructions are to use limit calculations to confirm, not the derivative rules (power rule, etc).